# Polymer bound property isn't updated

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm writing a simple i18n element for Polymer. The idea is to download translation, then keep it cached in local storage. I have problem with the following code, almost verbatim taken from https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-storage#polymerappstoragebehavior

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
<link rel="import" href="../app-storage/app-localstorage/app-localstorage-document.html">

<dom-module id="x-trans">
    <template>
        <iron-ajax id="ajax"
            handle-as="json"
            last-response="{{translation}}"
        ></iron-ajax>
        <app-localstorage-document session-only log id="localstorage"
            key="x-trans-translation"
            data="{{translation}}"
        >
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'x-trans',
            properties: {
                translation: {
                    type: Object,
                    value: {},
                    notify: true
                }
            });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

In my mind, this should:

- declare property `translation` with default value `{}`,
- fetch file (URL is configured at runtime) and save response to `translation`,
- store content of `translation` in local storage.

However, in following test:

```
test('retrieving translated string', function() {
                        var element = fixture('ajax');
                        request = element.$.ajax.generateRequest();
                        server.respond();
                        expect(request.response).to.be.ok;
                        expect(request.response).to.be.an('object');
                        expect(request.response['Hello world!']).to.be.equal('World, hello!');
                    });
```

`app-localstorage` log outputs:

```
Got stored value! undefined Object {  }
```

It appears to me that `translation` somehow retains it's default value, despite being bound, which should update it according to the docs. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you've shown looks correct (other than the omitted `iron-ajax` URL and the setup of `server`). ([demo](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/pNeQxa?editors=1010))

A couple notes:

- The default value of `translation` should be a function that returns an empty object. Setting it directly to an object would result in the object being shared across all instances of your element, which is probably not what you want.
- `handle-as="json"` is redundant because that's the default setting

I suspect `app-localstorage`'s log indicates you're getting an empty object because your mock `server` might be setup incorrectly.

Comment: I thought so, too, but `expect(request.response['Hello world!']).to.be.equal('World, hello!');` doesn't fail. However, I notice that `element.$.ajax.lastResponse` stays undefined. Is it wrong and what should I investigate to find the cause?

Comment: Okay, I found out that this is a peculiar behaviour of iron-ajax requests and responses... At the end of my test, `element.$.ajax.loading` is `true`, so response stil didn't reach the element somehow, `lastResponse` is undefined and `translation` doesn't get bound. Sorry for bothering and thanks for your input!